# Convert Single Line of Code to Block Format

Tags: vim, sed

I have a peice of malware that I managed to deofusacte into a single line of extremely bad looking javascript. I am looking for a way to break the whole thing up into a more manageable appearence. Can I perform a recursive call in `vim`/`sed` in which I break the code into bunchs based off the brackets and format it to my liking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's one line, does `==` just reformat it properly?

If not (I am not really familiar with the specifics of Vim's formatting), from what I know of JavaScript you might be able to add line breaks after `{`, `;`, and `}` and get a long way with that.

```
:%s/[{;}]/&\r/g
```

Then do `gg=G` to go to the top of the file and format it to the bottom.

If you don't mind doing a bit more work, and if the autoformatting after the fact fails to work, you could also do something like `/[{;}]` followed by `qaqqaa<Enter><Escape>nq@a` which will clear the 'a' register and then define a macro in that register that hits enter just after the character that was found, hits escape, then goes to the next match and does it again.  It's sort of dodgy but might work well enough for your needs.  (Press the enter and escape keys instead of typing the angle bracketed text in my string above, by the way.)

Comment: Thanks that got it close enough to where its accutally human readable.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can use a few substitutions based on brackets and semicolons but malware authors (and self-important JS ninja-rock-stars) like to drop them so this method might not work on your piece of code.

Stuff like:

```
:%s/{/{\r
:%s/};/\r};
```

Did you try [jsbeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/)?